# OpenGL - Displaying shape on click

Tags: animation, opengl, glut

I just started to learning GLUT & OpenGL and I need a help about displaying triangle when we click the button.

I draw an UFO and I want to display yellow triangle under the UFO as a light when we click on left button.

First, I wrote a function like:

```
void lightEffect() {
    glColor3ub(255, 204, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(xK - 100, yK + 33);
    glVertex2f(xK - 60, yK - 20);
    glVertex2f(xK - 140, yK - 20);
    glEnd();
}
```

and tried to call it like that:

```
void onClick(int button, int stat, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && stat == GLUT_DOWN)
        lightEffect();

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

However, if I don't call the function in the display function glutPostRedisplay will be useless, on the other side if I write it will not check whether I clicked or not. It will just display the light effect. Therefore, I'd appreciate if you guys help me.

Comment: Why don't state a global variable (`int light_on = 0;`) when the button is pressed in the `onClick` function `light_on = (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && stat == GLUT_DOWN);`. Now you can draw the light in the `display` function dependent on the state: `if (light_on) { lightEffect(); }`

Comment: Thank you mate! It worked you helped me a lot!